# Can a SQL Server 2005 msdb database be restored as a User database?

Tags: sql-server, restore, msdb

Can a SQL Server 2005 msdb database be restored as a User database on another instance (same Build)?

"Why?" you ask: I need a list of the mail items that existed prior to installation of two service packs .. the list was deleted (msdb.dbo.sysmail_delete_mailitems_sp) in order to address a post-install *storm* of mail messages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, even on the same instance.

```
-- I assume you've already done something like this:
BACKUP DATABASE msdb TO DISK = '<backup_location>\msdb.bak' WITH INIT;

RESTORE DATABASE msdb_copy FROM DISK = '<backup_location>\msdb.bak'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
  MOVE 'MSDBData' TO '<data folder>\msdb_copy.mdf',
  MOVE 'MSDBLog' TO '<data folder>\msdb_log.ldf';
```